# What security can cookies give to my website?

Tags: php, cookies

I am a beginner PHP programmer and wanting to continue learning everything that catches my attention, I analyze it until I understand it. I recently came across about 2 pages online, a store and a payment processing page like PayPal, and I see something curious, when I access the web page for the first time (for the first time I mean in an uncooked mode without cookies, cache ...), the page automatically makes me the following redirect:

```
https://example.com/ -> https://example.com/?secure=1
```

And once it redirects me (when it accesses for the first time) it creates a cookie with a value of type md5, and the most interesting thing is that that value does not change unless my IP address changes, the two web pages do the same. Also if I delete the cookie from the search engine manually it redirects me again as if it were entering for the first time.

I've tried googling about this for days but can't make sense of this. Can someone tell me what it can be, and what types of security can I integrate into a website with cookies and redirection? Also, say that sometimes the URL changes to:

```
/?secure=2
```

Could it be some framework feature like symfony or laravel?

Comment: Aren't you basically asking how cookies work and what they are used for - for example to identify the same user over multiple requests which is necessary to implement something like a shopping cart? I don't think that the example you provide is related to security either, it just means that it does not know that it is the same user (and thus cannot load the user specific shopping card) after the cookie was deleted.

Answer (score 6):

## Cookies are not a security measure

Judging from your description, you are both new to security and the inner workings of the web, so I will try to explain both concepts as beginner-friendly as possible.

First of all, security is not some singular *thing* you can just increase. Security can only exist as opposition to a specific threat. Compare that to cars: You cannot simply "make a car more secure", but you can make a car more secure against specific kinds of threats, such as front crashes, side crashes, etc.

### What are Cookies and what are they used for?

Due to the somewhat recent push by lawmakers to force websites to inform users that their website uses cookies, most web users are aware that they exist, but it's not immediately clear what they are and what they do.

In short, every cookie has at a minimum two things: A name, and a value. A website can instruct a browser to set a cookie, and the browser will save that cookie. Then, upon every further request from the browser to that site, the browser will send all the cookies to the server. It looks something like this:

> **Browser:** Hello, StackExchange. I would like to visit "security.stackexchange.com"
> **Server:** Hello browser. Here is "security.stackexchange.com"
>
> **Browser:** Hello, StackExchange. I would now like to log in. My name is MechMK1 and my password is "f0CGlLJZ"
> **Server:** Hello browser. You're now logged in. Please set the cookie "session" with the value "1234 5678 ABCD"
>
> **Browser:** Hello, StackExchange. I would like to change my display language to german now. Also my "session" cookie is "1234 5678
> ABCD"
> **Server:** Hello browser. I recognize you're MechMK1. Your display language is german now. Please set the cookie "lang" to "DE"
>
> **Browser:** Hello, StackExchange. I would like to ask a new question. Also my "session" cookie is "1234 5678 ABCD" and my "lang" cookie is
> "DE" 
> **Server:** Hello browser. I recognize you're MechMK1 and your preferred display language is german. Here is the new question page in
> german.

Why is this necessary at all? Can't the server just "remember" who I am? As it turns out, no. The web is based on HTTP, and HTTP is a so-called "stateless" protocol. It can't remember anything, and every request is treated by the web server as if it was the very first time you requested anything. Cookies were added so that browsers could repeatedly give servers all the information they need.

### What do cookies have to do with security?

Cookies are usually the target of attackers. As you saw in the above example, cookies can be used to tell a website who you are, so an attacker who can steal this cookie will be able to impersonate you. The web server quite literally cannot differentiate between an attacker and you if the attacker has your session cookie.

As such, a number of mechanisms have been created to make cookies more safe, such as the HTTPOnly flag or the Secure-flag in cookies. I won't explain those in detail, since that's not really the scope of the question, but you can read up on what they do.

Cookies can also be used to protect against specific kinds of attacks. I know, I said before that cookies are not a security measure, and my previous statement seems to contradict that. What I mean is that "Cookies, in general, are not a security measure. However, you can use cookies to protect against specific kinds of attacks". Specifically, *Cross-Site Request Forgery* attacks can be mitigated by the so-called "Double Submit Cookie Pattern", which would take another answer as a whole to explain.

### What did PayPal do with cookies?

In your question, you mention a specific kind of behavior exhibited by PayPal. The thing is, I cannot tell you what PayPal does with their cookies. Essentially, you send your cookies to PayPal and then their application server decides *whatever* based on those cookies. It could be that if you sent a cookie named "giveMeAllTheMoney" with the value "prettyPlease", that all the money on PayPal will be transferred to you - unlikely, but nobody except PayPal would be able to tell if that's the case or not.

What I can tell is that there is no golden bullet like setting `?secure=2` as query parameter or some other cookie that will magically make your site secure from all attacks.